# jquery check multiple inputs for value

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<form class=".form" action="">
  <input type="text" class="inputs"><br>
  <input type="text" class="inputs"><br>
</form>
<button>Check</button>


$("button").on("click", function () {
  if($(".inputs").val()) {
    $("body").css("background-color", "yellow");
  } else {
    $("body").css("background-color", "red");
  }
});
```

As you may see, I want to check for a value in inputs and based on that select a color for a body. The problem is, it checks only the first element among all of them.

You can try to enter a value in the second input and leave the first one empty and see this.

I want to check all of the inputs for a value with AND condition, how do I do this?

Thanks

Comment: What happens if someone enters values in both?

Comment: the background should change to yellow :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var $inputs = $('.inputs');
//logical OR, if any have a value
$inputs.filter(function(){ return this.value.trim(); }).length
//logical AND, if none of them do not have a value
$inputs.filter(function(){ return !this.value.trim(); }).length < 1
//logical AND, with just nots (!)
!$inputs.filter(function(){ return !this.value.trim(); }).length
```

This will return inputs that have a non blank value.  A length of > 0 being truthy.

Comment: This is awesome, to be honest. Even tho it doesn't really solve my problem(based on the above condition it would present OR instead of AND logic)